# RS-485 Modbus keeps sending set timeouts. Is it normal?

Tags: rs485, modbus

I try to monitor RS-485 communication between Toyo motor drivers and an IPC control program. I monitor with a third-party software Device monitoring studio. The program is written by us. However, I don't know why it keeps setting timeout parameters, no matter if we are giving RS-485 instructions to the driver or not. Is this normal?

Also, I noticed that if our control program opens the com port first, then when the monitoring program tries to open it, the access is denied, but can still see these setting timeouts instruction running. Are these timeout instructions wrong because two programs are not allowed to open the same com port at the same time from the same IPC? Or, if the grounding mistake leads to these wrong signals? Thank you.
[image]
[image]

Comment: So, what I gather, you are not using RS485 ground wire, and you don't know how a program made in your company works regarding the use of serial port? Can't you just read the source code or ask someone in your company why the software behaves like that?

Comment: In fact our program sends a Modbus command with the device number, address, data. It is not supposed to behave like that.

Comment: And, we use ground wire. It is my assumption that if wrong grounding causes abnormal siginal.

Comment: Superuser yes but how does your program handle the serial port, i.e. are you directly using win32 api or some libraries (C# serialport, pyserial, qtserial...)? No if your software constantly keeps setting COM port timeouts, it has nothing to do with ground wire..

Comment: Justme the problem is partly solved. Instead of monitoring from IPC, I use another laptop connected in serial as a slave, the mysterious set time out siginal dissapears. Then, sometimes some strange reading rigister commands behave in the same strange way. I pull and plug the RJ45 connector, then the strange siginal dissapears. It looks like strange siginal relates to a loose connector and not allow to monitor with the control program together in the same IPC.